# How to set tiny notification icon badge

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

How can I correctly set the round small badge that appears right on top of my app's notification's largeIcon in the picture below(I want to change the round ring which is the default to a picture)

[image: CAS]

like how the badge is the blue circle twitter logo here

[image: TWITTER]

I tried `Notification.buiilder.setSmallIcon()` but it doesn't work. Also am not sure if the name is called a notification badge, I tried checking the documentation but I didn't find anything relating.

Comment: It also looks that you use some kind of custom theme. Maybe its because of that. Notification Badge is the thing that comes up if you long press on a launcher icon with a notification.

Comment: I think this thing depends from version to version and if you want this view only then you can prepare a custom view but in this case if app is killed or in background notification will be generated by system and default UI will be there

Comment: I just checked that I don't have this icon on Nokia Android 9, or Huawei Smartphone Android 8. I've it on a trimble wich has nearly a stock android, but its only visible for system apps

Answer (score 1):

Use `setSmallIcon` method to set that icon.

```
notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_small_icon);
```

Comment: I made mention of that in the question. It still don't work. the small icon I set gets displayed for the ticker but it doesn't show up on top of the large notification icon. my small icon is **20px by 20px**

Comment: Yeah, but what is the resource your passing to it?

Comment: `NotificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.the_20px_by_20px_image)`